# Running a font preview

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a code that shows a name in a few different fonts, why my code isn't showing the name that typed  in the box?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
display_name {
font-family: "Adobe Arabic";
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Your name in Adobe Arabic font</h1>
<input id="word_input" type="text" spellcheck="false" value="Your Name"></input>
<p class="display_name" style="font-family:'Adobe Arabic': "></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reference a class, as the case with your paragraph tag, you must use a `.` ie: `.display_name{}`

If you're looking to source a local .otf font, then you should use a `@font-face`

```js
function bindFunction () {
  var input = document.getElementById('word_input').value;
  document.getElementsByClassName('display_name')[0].innerHTML = input;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Adobe Arabic";
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url("<path_to_font>font.otf") format("opentype");
}

.display_name {
  font-family: "Adobe Arabic";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <h1>Your name in Adobe Arabic font</h1>
  <input id="word_input" type="text" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Your Name" onkeyup="bindFunction()">
  <p class="display_name"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

- Guide to include fonts:
  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: It worked!!!Where do I place the function?

Comment: If you're looking to include it inline, similar to how you have included the css in the example provided, you can place it between '<script></script>' tags after the closing '</body> ' tag.

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/jmiramant/pen/xwJLXb

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the correct selectors for CSS

use .display_name

EIDT:

You currently have

```
<style>
display_name {
font-family: "Adobe Arabic";
}
</style>
```

use

```
<style>
.display_name {
font-family: "Adobe Arabic";
}
</style>
```

You forgot the . which is used as the class selector. without the . the styling wont affect anything at all.

EDIT 2: Use this to include the wordinput

```
<style>
#word_input, .display_name {
font-family: "Adobe Arabic";
}
</style>
```

See working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/y1g6j2g6/3/

Next time, please explain your issue and what you want done fully in the first post.

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: you currently have `<style>
display_name {
font-family: "Adobe Arabic";
}
</style>` Use `<style>
.display_name {
font-family: "Adobe Arabic";
}
</style>`

Comment: Still not working, looks like there isn't any connection between the 'word input' to the 'display name'.

Comment: Try the font helvetica, I will bet you the issue is that your default font is already Adobe Arabic and the change you don't notice because it is already that font.

Comment: Look here https://jsfiddle.net/y1g6j2g6/1/  I know this isn't the font you want but I am using it to show the change in fonts as Adobe Arabic is pretty close to the default. The added period in front of the display_name within the style block fixes your issue.

Comment: No it's just that the name that i'm writing in the box is not showing up underneath it with adobe arabic font.

Comment: Also, you have no text within the paragraph, so how can you tell if the font is changing?

Comment: I want the text being pulled from the input box

Comment: Look at my edit to the answer, BTW if I had known that from the original post this wouldnt have been so hard. Please tell us what you need done in the first place. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/y1g6j2g6/2/

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help, but let say that I'm writing Jason in the input box it is still not showing me 'Jason' underneath it with adobe font, it still shows 'Test'

Comment: You want the input box to display the text you put in under it? Thats a completely different issue.

Comment: Look, I think I didn't explain it right. It should AUTOMATICALLY display what you write it the box to the line under. you wrote 'Jason' in the <p> line, you should right it in the input box and then display it or any other name underneath it.